# Unable to configure port in Redis database

Tags: redis

I am trying to configure the ports in Redis database. I have changed the port number to 7778 in the `redis.conf` file. This file is in `/etc/redis.conf`

and I'm using this command

```
redis-server /etc/redis.conf
```

And this goes through. I'm able to get through. However if I execute this command

```
redis-cli
```

or

```
redis-cli /etc/redis.conf
```

I'm getting this error

```
could not connect to redis at 127.0.0.1:6379:connection refused.
```

I then tried this command

```
redis-cli -p 7778

127.0.0.1> ping
(error) NOAUTH authentication required
```

Answer (score 1):

1. 127.0.0.1> AUTH your password
2. OK               <--response from redis
3. (7.75s)          <--- it's too.
4. 127.0.0.1>ping   <--test if you want
5. PONG             <--you can receive response from redis
6. you can use AUTH keyword :) and after write your password.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem because I changed the bind IP address in `/etc/redis.conf`

So I manually set the host ip by using this command:

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.1.100 -p 7778
```

Then it started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
redis-cli -p 7778

127.0.0.1> ping
(error) NOAUTH authentication required
```

Port is working. But you need enter password:

```
>auth <yourpassword>
```

OR

```
redis-cli -p 7778 -a <yourpassword>
```

OR remove `requirepass` in /etc/redis.conf